# Measure theory: about bounded functions an intuitive question - curiosity

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ a domain  and $u \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ a non zero function. For each $c \in R$ define

$$ A_c:= \{ x \in \Omega \ ;c < |u(x)| < + \infty  \}.$$

Define $B: = \{ c \in R; |A_c| > 0\} $ an suppose that  $ B \neq \emptyset. $ We are supposing that $B$ is non empty and since $B$ is bounded (because $u \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$) then exist $sup \ B.$ My question is : the equality $sup \ B = \| u\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}$ is true? Intuitively is true, but I dot know how to prove or disprove ... Someone could help me with a proof /counter example?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I think you have $||u||_\infty \notin B$ because the set on which $u$ exceeds this value has measure zero. Oh, wait. I see. but it could still be the supremum. Ok nevermind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $c > \|u\|_\infty$, we have $|u| \leq c$ almost everywhere and hence $|A_c| = 0$. This shows $B \subset (-\infty, \|u\|_\infty)$ and hence $\sup B \leq \|u\|_\infty$.

Conversely, for $c > \sup B$, we have $c \notin B$ and hence $|A_c| = 0$ which means $|u(x)| \leq c$ almost everywhere. Hence, $\|u\|_\infty \leq c$. Since $c > \sup B$ was arbitrary, we get $\|u\|_\infty \leq \sup B$.